# Convert POJO to a GSON to JSON

Tags: json, gson

I'm trying to send a JSON post request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail to send an email.

I created a POJO with getters and setters so I can set the json value dynamically.

SendEmail.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class SendEmail {
   
    public class Body{
        public String contentType;
        public String content;

        public void setContentType(String contentType) {
            this.contentType = contentType;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            return contentType;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
    }

    public class CcRecipient{
        public EmailAddress emailAddress;

        public void setEmailAddress(SendEmail.EmailAddress emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public SendEmail.EmailAddress getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }
    }

    public class EmailAddress{
        public String address;

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
    }

    public class Message{
        public String subject;
        public Body body;
        public ArrayList<ToRecipient> toRecipients;
        public ArrayList<CcRecipient> ccRecipients;

        public void setSubject(String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        public String getSubject() {
            return subject;
        }

        public void setBody(SendEmail.Body body) {
            this.body = body;
        }

        public SendEmail.Body getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setToRecipients(ArrayList<SendEmail.ToRecipient> toRecipients) {
            this.toRecipients = toRecipients;
        }

        public ArrayList<SendEmail.ToRecipient> getToRecipients() {
            return toRecipients;
        }

        public void setCcRecipients(ArrayList<SendEmail.CcRecipient> ccRecipients) {
            this.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
        }

        public ArrayList<SendEmail.CcRecipient> getCcRecipients() {
            return ccRecipients;
        }
    }

    public class Root{
        public Message message;
        public String saveToSentItems;

        public void setMessage(SendEmail.Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public SendEmail.Message getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setSaveToSentItems(String saveToSentItems) {
            this.saveToSentItems = saveToSentItems;
        }

        public String getSaveToSentItems() {
            return saveToSentItems;
        }
    }

    public class ToRecipient{
        public EmailAddress emailAddress;

        public void setEmailAddress(SendEmail.EmailAddress emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public SendEmail.EmailAddress getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }
    }


}
```

Below is the test class. The jsonRequest is empty. How can I put the correct JSON values using my POJO?

Test.java

```
SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
    
    SendEmail.Message message = sendEmail.new Message();
    message.setSubject("Test subject");
    
    SendEmail.Body body = sendEmail.new Body();
    body.setContent("this is a test body on an email");
    
    SendEmail.ToRecipient toRecipient = sendEmail.new ToRecipient();
    
    SendEmail.EmailAddress emailAddress = sendEmail.new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.setAddress("dummyemail@outlook.com");
    toRecipient.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
   
    String accessToken = connectEmail(); System.out.println("ACCESS TOKEN: "+accessToken);
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonRequest = gson.toJson(toRecipient);
    
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail");
        
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken);
           
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                  
        try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {                
            System.out.println("jsonRequest: "+jsonRequest);               
            os.write(jsonRequest.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION SENDING EMAIL");   
    }
```

Below is the sample post request I need to write using values from the POJO.

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "frannis@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Gson and Jackson? Your `SendEmail` class has Jackson imports but your code `Test` class uses Gson. What do you mean by "The jsonRequest is empty"? Does your `println` call really print an empty string, or does it print `null` or `{}`?

Comment: One issue with your code is that all nested classes of `SendEmail` are not `static`. Please make them `static`. Also, when calling `jsonRequest.getBytes()` you should specify a charset to not be affected by your OS charset: `jsonRequest.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: @Marcono1234, it prints {}

Comment: Are you using a code shrinking tool such as ProGuard or R8 (respectively, are you creating an Android app)?